# Sublists of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I wanted to know how do append function work for sublists of lists in Python

If we create a list as:

```
a =  [[]]*4
```

and append as:

```
a[0].append(10)
```

The **output** of printing a was:

```
[[10],[10],[10,[10]]
```

Why does 10 get copied in all four sublists while it should just for the first one??? i.e.

```
[[10],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: In other words, you absolutely do not have four sublists, you have *one* sublist with four references to it.

Comment: I'd like to especially highlight [this article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) in the linked answer, which is a must-read for newcomers to python.